# regular expression in R-- new lines

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to using regular expression in R by using regexpr function. I have multiple conditions to match, therefore my regular expression is very long actually, for example "A\s+(\d+)|(\d+)\s+A". So I want to put each separate expression on different lines, like

```
"A\\s+(\\d+)|
(\\d+)\\s+A|"
```

But it's not working. The bracket tells R that I want to extract the digit number out. Can anyone give suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**1) paste** Try using `paste`:

```
paste("A\\s+(\\d+)", 
      "(\\d+)\\s+A", 
      sep = "|")
```

**2) rex** Another possibility is to use the [rex package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rex)

```
library(rex)

rex(group("A", spaces, capture(digits)) %or% 
    group(capture(digits), spaces, "A"))
```

which gives:

```
(?:(?:A[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+))|(?:([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]+A))
```

**3) rebus** The [rebus package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rebus) is similar in intent:

```
library(rebus)

literal("A") %R% one_or_more(space()) %R% capture(one_or_more(ascii_digit())) %|% 
capture(one_or_more(digit())) %R% one_or_more(space()) %R% literal("A")
```

which emits:

```
<regex> \QA\E[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)|([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]+\QA\E
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. I used to use perl to deploy the task and my old way worked. I just haven't been familiar enough with R. :)

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. You might want to accept and/or upvote the answer, since, as you have stated, it covers you. (To accept an answer, that press at that green tick at the left of this answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break string literal up on to several lines in your script, one solution is to use `paste0`:

```
my_expr <- paste0('partone',
                  'parttwo',
                  'partthree')
```

Then you get the desired result:

```
> my_expr
[1] "partoneparttwopartthree"
```

You can't just break it up onto several lines in between quotes, b/c then the new line character is part of the expression.

If you are also trying to trouble shoot your regular expression, you'll need to post a sample of the data you are trying to work with and the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [**x modifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) with `perl = TRUE` in whatever function you're using.   Place the x modifier (`(?x)`) at the beginning of the expression and white space is ignored.  Additionally, comment charcters are ignored as well.

```
pat <- "(?x)\\\\                  ## Grab a backslash followed by...
    [a-zA-Z0-9]*cite[a-zA-Z0-9]*  ## A word that contains ‘cite‘
    (\\[([^]]+)\\]){0,2}\\**      ## Look for 0-2 square brackets w/ content
    \\{([a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+)\\}"       ## Look for curly braces with viable bibkey

tex <- c(
    "Many \\parencite*{Ted2005, Moe1999} say graphs \\textcite{Few2010}.",
    "But \\authorcite{Ware2013} said perception good too.",
    "Random words \\pcite[see][p. 22]{Get9999c}.",
    "Still more \\citep[p. 22]{Foo1882c}?"
)

gsub(pat, "", tex, perl=TRUE)

## [1] "Many  say graphs ."             "But  said perception good too."
## [3] "Random words ."                 "Still more ?"
```

A second approach...I maintain a package called [**regexr**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/regexr/index.html) that attempts to enable maintainers of regular expressions libraries:

> to write regular expressions in a way that is similar to the ways R code is written.

This may be overkill if you're aren't panning long term maintence of the expression but you could do the same thing with **regexr** by (no need for `perl = TRUE`).  Note the minimal comments as the meaning is shared with sub expression names.  The `%:)%` is a comment operator (commented code is happy code) but you need not use the leading names or comments, just `construct`.:

```
library(regexr)
pat2 <- construct(
    backslash    = "\\\\"                          %:)% "\\",
    cite_command = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*cite[a-zA-Z0-9]*"  %:)% "parencite",
    square_brack = "(\\[([^]]+)\\]){0,2}\\**"      %:)% "[e.g.][p. 12]",
    bibkeys      = "\\{([a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+)\\}"        %:)% "{Rinker2014}"
)

gsub(pat2, "", tex)

## [1] "Many  say graphs ."             "But  said perception good too."
## [3] "Random words ."                 "Still more ?"
```

The **regexr** frame work requires a bit of upfront time but the "code" is much easier to maintain, more modular, and easier to understand by others without learning a new "language".  This is one approach of many and I tend to use a combination  of standard regex, **regexr** and **rebus** (which works within the **regexr** framework).  So for example we can grab any of the sub expressions from `pat2` with the `subs` function as follows:

```
subs(pat2)

## $backslash
## [1] "\\\\"
## 
## $cite_command
## [1] "[a-zA-Z0-9]*cite[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
## 
## $square_brack
## [1] "(\\[([^]]+)\\]){0,2}\\**"
## 
## $bibkeys
## [1] "\\{([a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+)\\}"
```

I also included  simple way to test the main and sub expressions for perl validity as follows:

```
test(pat2)

## $regex
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $subexpressions
##    backslash cite_command square_brack      bibkeys 
##         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
```